# How to install specific version of an R package while also installing dependencies, without install_version()?

Tags: r

I am trying to install an older version (1.6.3) of the 'usethis' package, because the package 'gert' can't be correctly configured with latest version (2.0.0) in my environment (AWS EMR 5.15.0): it shows 'configuration failed for package gert' when installing usethis.
In this case, I can't use install_version() because install_version() is part of the 'devtools' package, which depends on usethis.
I tried to use install.package() as follows:

```
packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/usethis/usethis_1.6.3.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

However, in this way, the dependent packages are not installed and the installation can't be done. While I try this:

```
packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/usethis/usethis_1.6.3.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos="http://cran.rstudio.com", type="source")
```

It shows error of package "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/usethis/usethis_1.6.3.tar.gz" not available for R(3.6.3), I believe it is because R interpret the URL to be a package name rather than URL when repos is not NULL.
How should I install a specific version while asking R to install dependencies? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Hao, have you find a solution? I have the same need and problem